JSPdf and HTML2Canvas rendering issue
I am using JSPdf with HTM2Canvas to export to server my webpage and when I render the webpage, the form input box text gets cut off at the bottom. I have tried different suggestions (scale, lineheight etc) but cannot solve the issue. I have included an image of the problem. Can anyone suggest a solution. This is frustrating me no end.

<script>
    async function saveAsPDF() {
        
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;

        // Combine content and form data
        const content = document.getElementById('content').outerHTML;
        const form = document.getElementById('Course-Builder').outerHTML;
        const combinedContent = content + form;

        const canvas = await html2canvas(document.body, { 
            useCORS: true,
            scale: 2,
        });
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4", true);

        const fontSize = 10;
        pdf.setFontSize(fontSize);

        const lineHeight = 1; // Line height based on font size

        var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

        //var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ......';

        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 0, width, height);

        const pdfData = pdf.output('blob');

        // Get form email value
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;

        // Send the PDF data to the server
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('email', email);
        formData.append('pdf', pdfData, '/uploads/webpreferences.pdf');

        // Send the PDF to the server
        try { const response = await fetch('/php/save_pdf.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        });
           const result = await response.json();

            if (result.success) {
                alert('PDF generated and sent successfully!');
            } else {
                alert('There was an error generating the PDF.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('There was an error processing your request.');
        }
    }

